# Upload a file from Android to Drupal via Services Module

Tags: android, drupal, service, upload

I tried to upload an image from Android Device to a Drupal Website

I used the Service module on Drupal side with method file.create.

The problem is that the files has been broken after the download.

The Files are smaller.

The filemime setting has n effect.

Javaside:

```
public Map saveFile(String localFilePath, String serverpath) throws XmlRpcException, IOException{


        HashMap<String, Object> account = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    File localFile = new File(localFilePath);

    Log.w("XMLRPC", "FILENAME "+localFile.getName() + " original "+localFile.length());



        String fileAsString = readFile(localFilePath);

        // Sending side
        byte[] data =  fileAsString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] base64 =  Base64.encode(data,Base64.URL_SAFE);

        account.put("file", base64);
        account.put("filename", localFile.getName());
        account.put("filepath", serverpath +"/"+ localFile.getName());
       // account.put("filemime", "application/x-compressed");
        account.put("filesize", Integer.parseInt(localFile.length()+""));//String.valueOf(localFile.length()));

        Vector<Object> params = new Vector<Object>();
        params.add(account);


        return (Map) xmlRpcClient.execute(METHOD_FILE_CREATE, params);
    }
```

Comment: The filemime really has no effect, because it's replaced in file.create handler at server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are not using a native android app for your Drupal site, you do not need any other 'interface' to upload the file! It should work as if you are uploading the file from desktop!